# Query Run fine in mysql but stuck on Java

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

hello  can anyone tell me whats wrong with that query

```
select d.id as 'id',d.date as 'date',min(d.time) as 'timein' 
from emp_list b,num_run_days c, attendance d,user_of_run2 a 
where a.User_ID='4' and a.User_ID=d.id and d.time BETWEEN time(c.startin) 
and time(c.startout) AND a.Num_of_run=c.Num_RunID AND 
c.s_Days=DAYOFWEEK(d.Date) group by d.Date
```

when run in mysql its work fine but when its run through java my jre stuck...
here is java code

```
 String query41="select d.id as 'id',d.date as 'date',min(d.time) as 'timein' from attendance d,emp_list b,num_run_days c, user_of_run2 a where a.User_ID='4' and a.User_ID=d.id and d.time BETWEEN time(c.startin) and time(c.startout) AND a.Num_of_run=c.Num_RunID AND c.s_Days=DAYOFWEEK(d.Date) group by d.Date";
    //in PreparedStatement 
    pst41=con.prepareStatement(query41); 
    ResultSet rst41= pst41.executeQuery(query41); 
    tablen.setModel (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rst41));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post java code you are using this with too

Comment: does java program throw some exception?

Comment: String query41="select d.id as 'id',d.date as 'date',min(d.time) as 'timein' from attendance d,emp_list b,num_run_days c, user_of_run2 a where a.User_ID='4' and a.User_ID=d.id and d.time BETWEEN time(c.startin) and time(c.startout) AND a.Num_of_run=c.Num_RunID AND c.s_Days=DAYOFWEEK(d.Date) group by d.Date";//in
            PreparedStatement pst41=con.prepareStatement(query41);
            ResultSet rst41=
            pst41.executeQuery(query41);
           
           tablen.setModel (DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rst41));

Comment: try catch exception

Answer (score 0):

try to remove "as" in you query

```
    select d.id 'id',d.date 'date',min(d.time) 'timein' 
from emp_list b,num_run_days c, attendance d,user_of_run2 a 
where a.User_ID='4' and a.User_ID=d.id and d.time BETWEEN time(c.startin) 
and time(c.startout) AND a.Num_of_run=c.Num_RunID AND 
c.s_Days=DAYOFWEEK(d.Date) group by d.Date
```

Comment: SELECT attendance.id 'id', attendance.date 'date', min(attendance.time) 'timein' from user_of_run2 a JOIN attendance d ON d.id = a.User_ID JOIN num_run_days c ON c.Num_RunID = a.Num_of_run WHERE a.User_ID='4' AND ( d.time BETWEEN time(c.startin) and time(c.startout) ) AND c.s_Days=DAYOFWEEK(d.Date) group by d.Date